# Create SQL table with SQL keyword column

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, create-table

I am trying to create SQL table with SQL keyword column named "lock", but "lock" seems is a SQL keyword where the workbench thought I would want to execute the "lock" function.

```
Create table A(
Lock Varchar(255)
);
```

*Putting the "Lock" into a square bracket --> [lock] doesn't work for me.

Comment: use backtick like ` Lock `

Comment: Thank you so much! It works

Comment: Please take a look at this [**POST**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: I strongly suggest that you have a different column name instead

Comment: I cannot have a different column name as the structure is fixed by another software. However it's already fixed by using backtick. Thank you so much

Comment: That's a strange response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL uses the ` character to escape object names:

```
Create table A(
    `Lock` Varchar(255)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should put back ticks ` around the reserved word:

```
Create table A(
   `Lock` Varchar(255)
);
```

**[You can find a good explanation about reserved words and the list of them here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)**

> Certain objects within MySQL, including database, table, index, column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, tablespace, and other object names are known as identifiers.
>
> If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it.

You should try to avoid the use of this words, it may be confusing for some people to watch a code with this name. Try adding a logical name to it , like `TabName_Lock`.